# Including dynamic content in documentation generated by Python Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

I am using Sphinx to generate documentation for my project, and building the documentation as part of the product's install process.

I would like to dynamically include the hostname in the text and/or code-blocks. I have not seen any explanations in the documentation nor any facility for including the output of a shell command or anything other than specific line(s) from a specific file. Does this functionality exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are two Sphinx [extensions](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/index.html) that can do this:

- [autorun](https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-autorun/): executes Python  code in `runblock` directives, captures the output and inserts it into documents.
- [programoutput](https://pypi.org/project/sphinxcontrib-programoutput/): executes arbitrary commands using the `program-output` directive and inserts the output into documents.

Comment: As of December 2022, both extensions work for me (Python 3.10.7, Sphinx 5.3.0). With `autorun`, I get this warning: https://github.com/WhyNotHugo/sphinx-autorun/issues/20, but it still produces output.