# Is it possible to execute Python scripts within a rst file?

Tags: python, restructuredtext

I have multiple example scripts in a rst file (for documentation purposes), is it possible to make a script that will go through and run them all? Also, if not, would there be a better way to document these examples so it's easier to test?

It looks something like this:

```
********
Examples
********

Example 1
=========

::

   *SCRIPT 1*


Example 2
=========

::

   *SCRIPT 2*
```

Comment: [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/doctest.html) could do it if it properly formatted doctests

Comment: That's possible. Have fun implementing it! If you have a specific question or get stuck please ask!

Comment: If you use Sphinx, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/16072086/407651. Sphinx also has support for doctest: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/doctest.html.

Comment: [Pylit](https://codeberg.org/milde/pylit) comes with an option to run all doctests in a rST file or comments of a Python module.